# Why is if statement in this function never true

Tags: xcode, swift, if-statement

I have a function in swift UIview that makes 2 mp4`s loop. The first mp4 is playing fine but the second one is not, it only seems to play once, how could i fix this?

```
let videoURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(instrumentaimp4[skaicius], withExtension: "mp4")!
        let sakeleURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("sakele_blikas", withExtension: "mp4")!

        player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
        player?.actionAtItemEnd = .None
        player?.muted = true

        sakele = AVPlayer(URL: sakeleURL)
        sakele?.actionAtItemEnd = .None
        sakele?.muted = true


        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.zPosition = 1

        let playerLayer2 = AVPlayerLayer(player: sakele)
        playerLayer2.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        playerLayer2.zPosition = 1



        view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer2)
        view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        player?.play()
        sakele?.play()


        //loop video
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: "loopVideo:",
            name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
            object:nil)








func loopVideo(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let finishedPlayer = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem!{

        if finishedPlayer == self.sakele {
            self.sakele?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
            self.sakele?.play()
            NSLog("1")
        }else{
            self.player?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
            self.player?.play()
            NSLog("2")}
    }}
```

NSLog ("2") never happens. Where is my mistake? any help apreciated

Comment: post the complete code, the method loop video is missing a close brace.

Comment: If "player" does not play the else statement will never be reached as the end of play notification will never be fired. Are you sure the video url is correct? since you are using it as optional player?.play() might not work but the code will still run with no errors

Comment: the video plays once, it just doesn`t loop, if the url was wrong woulnt it not appear at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sakele` is an AVPlayer. But your `notification.object` is claimed to be (and is cast to) an AVPlayerItem, which is then assigned to `finishedPlayer`. This makes no sense. When you come to compare `if finishedPlayer == self.sakele`, it can never succeed, because they are not the same *kind* of object, let alone the same object.

Comment: okay, how would i go about writing this if statement then, so it could succeed? c

Comment: Your question was: "Where is my mistake?" I believe I have answered that very clearly.

Comment: sorry for a poorly worded question. a vaguely understood where my mistake was i just didnt know how to fix it.

Comment: I am not here to write your code for you, but rather to help your understanding. Thinking is up to you. You receive an AVPlayerItem in the notification. Think about how you will determine what AVPlayer it belongs to.